# Недопустимое значение ключа "attachdbfilename"

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

Создал проект по шаблону MVC, добавил в папку App_Data папку DataBase с базой UserStore.mdf. Решил к ней подключится и вылетело исключение с текстом: `Недопустимое значение ключа "attachdbfilename".`. Путь к файлу я проверил, делал по [примеру](http://cybern.ru/adonetconnecttobase.html).

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="userStore" 
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase\UserStore.mdf;User Instance=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Подключение я писал в Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["userStore"].ConnectionString;

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);//Вот тут исключение ArgumentException
        con.Open();
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте указать `.\SQLEXPRESS` вместо `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`.